# Change CSS property only in getElementsByName

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Looking for a way to change the CSS property by certain names.

Down below I have an example using checkboxes. There are two types that are generally the same unless changeSpecialCheckBox() occurs with a true value within its parameter.

file.css

```css
.checkBoxApperance {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: 'dark-blue';
}
```

file.html

```html
<!--regularCheckBox-->
<div class="checkBoxApperance">
   <input type="checkbox" id="regularCheckBox1" name="regularCheckBox"/>
</div>
<div class="checkBoxApperance">
   <input type="checkbox" id="regularCheckBox2" name="regularCheckBox"/>
</div>
<div class="checkBoxApperance">
   <input type="checkbox" id="regularCheckBox3" name="regularCheckBox"/>
</div>

<!--specialCheckBox-->
<div class="checkBoxApperance">
   <input type="checkbox" id="specialCheckBox1" name="specialCheckBox"/>
</div>
<div class="checkBoxApperance">
   <input type="checkbox" id="specialCheckBox2" name="specialCheckBox"/>
</div>
<div class="checkBoxApperance">
   <input type="checkbox" id="specialCheckBox3" name="specialCheckBox"/>
</div>
```

file.js

```js
function changeSpecialCheckBox(condition)
{
  if(condition) {
    document.getElementsByName("specialCheckBox").forEach(elem => {
      elem.disabled = true;
      $('.checkBoxApperance').css("background-color" , "light-blue"); //change the appearance
                                                                     //of all checkboxes
                                                                     //instead of all checkboxes under
                                                                     //the "specialCheckBox" name
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery, why use `getElementsByName()` at all? You could just select that name using a jQuery selector, then apply the style/disabled property to that selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery to set the style, then you can use `$("[name='name']")` to select the elements directly instead of combining jQuery with the vanilla JS `getElementsByName()`. This way you can chain the operations to only apply your changes to the relevant selection of elements, like this:

```js
// You can run this inside the function/condition you want
$("[name='specialCheckBox']") // Selects the elements with the matching name
  .prop("disabled", true) // Sets the disabled property
  .closest(".checkBoxApperance") // Finds the parent div
  .css("background-color", "lightblue") // Applies the new style to the parent
```

```css
.checkBoxApperance {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--regularCheckBox-->
<div class="checkBoxApperance">
  <input type="checkbox" id="regularCheckBox1" name="regularCheckBox" />
</div>
<div class="checkBoxApperance">
  <input type="checkbox" id="regularCheckBox2" name="regularCheckBox" />
</div>
<div class="checkBoxApperance">
  <input type="checkbox" id="regularCheckBox3" name="regularCheckBox" />
</div>

<!--specialCheckBox-->
<div class="checkBoxApperance">
  <input type="checkbox" id="specialCheckBox1" name="specialCheckBox" />
</div>
<div class="checkBoxApperance">
  <input type="checkbox" id="specialCheckBox2" name="specialCheckBox" />
</div>
<div class="checkBoxApperance">
  <input type="checkbox" id="specialCheckBox3" name="specialCheckBox" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can simply use [Node.parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) to target the parent element of the `'specialCheckBox'` elements:

```js
function changeSpecialCheckBox(condition) {
  if (condition) {
    document.getElementsByName('specialCheckBox').forEach(elem => {
      elem.disabled = true;
      elem.parentNode.style.background = 'lightblue'
    })
  }
}

changeSpecialCheckBox(1)
```

```css
.checkBoxApperance {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkBoxApperance">
  <input type="checkbox" id="regularCheckBox1" name="regularCheckBox" />
</div>
<div class="checkBoxApperance">
  <input type="checkbox" id="regularCheckBox2" name="regularCheckBox" />
</div>
<div class="checkBoxApperance">
  <input type="checkbox" id="regularCheckBox3" name="regularCheckBox" />
</div>

<!--specialCheckBox-->
<div class="checkBoxApperance">
  <input type="checkbox" id="specialCheckBox1" name="specialCheckBox" />
</div>
<div class="checkBoxApperance">
  <input type="checkbox" id="specialCheckBox2" name="specialCheckBox" />
</div>
<div class="checkBoxApperance">
  <input type="checkbox" id="specialCheckBox3" name="specialCheckBox" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 const checkBoxApperanceElemnts =
      document.getElementsByClassName("checkBoxApperance");
    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxApperanceElemnts.length; i++) {
      const root = checkBoxApperanceElemnts[i];
      const el = root.querySelectorAll('[name="specialCheckBox"]');
      if (el[0]) {
        root.style.background = "red";
      }
    }
```

```css
.checkBoxApperance {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: 'dark-blue';
}
```

```html
<html>
  <bod>
    <!--regularCheckBox-->
    <div class="checkBoxApperance">
      <input type="checkbox" id="regularCheckBox1" name="regularCheckBox" />
    </div>
    <div class="checkBoxApperance">
      <input type="checkbox" id="regularCheckBox2" name="regularCheckBox" />
    </div>
    <div class="checkBoxApperance">
      <input type="checkbox" id="regularCheckBox3" name="regularCheckBox" />
    </div>
    <div class="checkBoxApperance">
      <input type="checkbox" id="specialCheckBox1" name="specialCheckBox" />
    </div>
    <div class="checkBoxApperance">
      <input type="checkbox" id="specialCheckBox2" name="specialCheckBox" />
    </div>
    <div class="checkBoxApperance">
      <input type="checkbox" id="specialCheckBox3" name="specialCheckBox" />
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```